# How to get accuracy precision, recall and ROC from cross validation in Spark ml lib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, precision-recall

I am using Spark 2.0.2. I am also using the "ml" library for Machine Learning with Datasets. What I want to do is run algorithms with cross validation and extract the mentioned metrics (accuracy, precision, recall, ROC, confusion matrix). My data labels are binary.

By using the MulticlassClassificationEvaluator I can only get the accuracy of the algorithm by accessing "avgMetrics". Also, by using the BinaryClassificationEvaluator I can get the area under ROC. But I cannot use them both. 
So, is there a way that I can extract all of the wanted metrics?

Answer (score 2):

Have tried to use MLlib to evaluate your result.

I've transformed the dataset to RDD, then used [MulticlassMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics) in MLlib

You can see a demo here: [Spark DecisionTreeExample.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/DecisionTreeExample.scala)

```
private[ml] def evaluateClassificationModel(
      model: Transformer,
      data: DataFrame,
      labelColName: String): Unit = {
    val fullPredictions = model.transform(data).cache()
    val predictions = fullPredictions.select("prediction").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))
    val labels = fullPredictions.select(labelColName).rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))
    // Print number of classes for reference.
    val numClasses = MetadataUtils.getNumClasses(fullPredictions.schema(labelColName)) match {
      case Some(n) => n
      case None => throw new RuntimeException(
        "Unknown failure when indexing labels for classification.")
    }
    val accuracy = new MulticlassMetrics(predictions.zip(labels)).accuracy
    println(s"  Accuracy ($numClasses classes): $accuracy")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the official **Evaluation Metrics guide** provided by Apache Spark.
The document has provided all the Evaluation Metrics including

- Precision (Positive Predictive Value), Recall (True Positive Rate),
  F-measure, Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC), Area Under ROC
  Curve, Area Under Precision-Recall Curve.

Here is the link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

Comment: thank you, but this is RDD-Based and it uses "mllib" library. I work with dataframes and datasets and "ml" lib.

Comment: Oh Sorry for that. Check this [link](https://www.mapr.com/blog/predicting-breast-cancer-using-apache-spark-machine-learning-logistic-regression) maybe you get something. I'm not much familiar with ml.